# C++ - std::vector foreach - no instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, foreach, stl

I can't figure this one; I recently started to use `std::for_each` but this one is a pain to solve

I keep receiving an error for the code below :

```
**no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=CharacterObject *, _Alloc=std::allocator<CharacterObject *>]" matches the argument list**
```

code:

```
class Stuff
{
};  

std::vector< Stuff* > list;
list.push_back(new Stuff());
list.push_back(new Stuff());
list.push_back(new Stuff());

std::vector< Stuff* > stuffs;

std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [this,level, stuff](Stuff &stuff) 
{
    ... // some conditions here
    stuffs.push_back(stuff);  << error
    stuffs.push_back(&stuff);  << also throws an error
});
```

I tried many different combinations, but it's hard to figure anything with STL template errors

Any help greatly appreciated of course

sheers

[edit: there, works like acharm and no need for bad faith I consider extremely obnoxious]

```
for (std::vector< CharacterObject* >::iterator it = spawnedCharactersObjects.begin(); it != spawnedCharactersObjects.end(); ++it)
{
    CharacterObject* characterObject = *it;
    if (characterObject->getLevel() == level)
    {
        characterObjects.push_back(characterObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You're trying to push a concrete object into a vector of pointers. `characterObject.getLevel()` clearly indicates `characterObject` is an object; not a pointer. Your vector object type is `_Ty=CharacterObject *`, which is a pointer type. They're not the same.

Comment: ok if you take it like this, I'll use regular good old for(...

Comment: I tried pushing &characterObject did not work

Comment: dude I tried to push_back the pointer of the object, it does not work, hence the question

Comment: nevermind , I'll use for(...thanks

Comment: In the current example, you're capturing `stuffs` by value i.e. you're duplicating the variable and pushing back to _that_ instead of pushing back to the original, uncopied version of `stuffs`.  (Also, I'm kinda just assuming that you meant to capture `stuffs` and not `stuff`.)

Comment: @phil123456 1) Please provide [mcve]. You are trying to capture non-existing variable `stuff`, while not capturing `stuffs`, to which you are trying to `push_back`. 2) `for (std::vector< CharacterObject* >::iterator it = spawnedCharactersObjects.begin(); it != spawnedCharactersObjects.end(); ++it)` can be changed to `for (auto& elem : spawnedCharactersObjects)`.

Comment: call it bad faith if you like, but we cannot help you when the code you post is not the code that produces the error you are trying to fix, thats why you were kindly asked to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This is how it would be done correct

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Stuff
{
};  

int main() {
    std::vector< Stuff* > list;
    list.push_back(new Stuff());
    list.push_back(new Stuff());
    list.push_back(new Stuff());

    std::vector< Stuff* > stuffs;

    std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), [&stuffs] (Stuff *stuff) {
        stuffs.push_back(stuff);
    });
    return 0;
}
```

`std::for_each` is a template function of kind

```
std::for_each(Container<Type>::iterator, Container<Type>::iterator, void(Type))
```

(That's not correct but it shows the relation between the iterator and the unary function).
 It expects as third parameter a function with one parameter of type `Stuff *` since `list` is a container containing elements of that type. Both types have to be same. Also you have to capture `stuffs` as reference if you want to change it.